# jQuery UI resizable does not work on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm storing a few `resizable` and `draggable` div tags in my database through admin dashboard and outputting them on my main website. But the problem is, `resizable`does not work but I managed to make `draggable` work.

**Here's my DOM coming from database:**

```
<div data-type="input" data-card="serial_no" data-title="Serial No" class="card-data card-text card-content serial_no serial_no_content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable"><span>Content for Serial No</span>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

*NOTE: I wrapped above DOM in a div tag with a class `.card`*

You can see `ui-resizable-handle` and `ui-resizable-*` classes are already there and I tried the following after outputting the DOM in a wrapper having a class name `.card`.

```
$(function(){

   /**
    * Searching for .card children with the class name .ui-resizable-handle
    * and removing them
    **/
   $('.card').find('.ui-resizable-handle').each(function(i, v){
      $(v).remove();
   });


   /**
    * Iterating through .card again and making it's children draggable and resizable but this does not work.
    **/
   $('.card').children().each(function(i, v){
      if($(v).attr('data-type') == 'input'){
        $(v).draggable({containment: '.card-wrapper'}).resizable({
          handles: "n, e, s, w"
        });
      }
   });
});
```

After doing this, `draggable` works but `resizable` does not.

Please help me out to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit:***
Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkob3sft/4/)

Comment: if you could make a functioning example either through a jsfiddle (or equivalent) or snippet would help.

Comment: is your `v` a dynamic element?

Comment: Yes @AnandG. I'm using jQuery $.each iterator to iterate through all of the child elements of .card which suppose to be obviously `resizable`.

Comment: did you check `v` element has  `draggable ` class?

Comment: @AnandG not `draggable` but `ui-draggable` and  `ui-draggable-handle`

Comment: Hi, you're missing the jquery ui css. when I add it to your fiddle it works fine. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css

Comment: Yeah I managed to fixed it on that day. The strange thing is it worked without jQuery ui css as well before and still working as long as I was storing the history log in `localStorage`. But the problem arise when I was trying to display the dom coming from database and i got it fixed with the jquery ui theme stylesheet.

Comment: Here's my [Fiddle](http://https://jsfiddle.net/zhtvyx4q/6/) which i forgot to share that day in which i fixed it myself

Answer (score 0):

Two things I found odd,

1. You are removing child elements and later trying to add `resizable` on
   same.
2. You are binding `draggable` and `resizable` at the same time.
   It does not work since the return of the `draggable` is not
   an instance of the element.

I have tried to fix your issue abe below

```js
$(function() {

  /**
   * Iterating through .card again and making it's children draggable and resizable but this does not work.
   **/
  $('.card').children().each(function(i, v) {
    if ($(v).attr('data-type') == 'input') {
      $(v).resizable({
        handles: "n, e, s, w"
      });
      $(v).draggable({
        containment: '.card-wrapper'
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  outline: solid 1px #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.card .card-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- div with the class .card is not dynamic but it's content is which is coming from database and i'm using PHP & MySQL for backend -->
<div class="card">
  <div data-type="input" data-card="serial_no" data-title="Serial No" class="card-data card-text card-content serial_no serial_no_content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable"><span>Content for Serial No</span>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n">foo</div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e">too</div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s">poo</div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w">choo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your solution does not work. Basically, making an element `resizable` and `draggable` does two things. 

1 - Adds `ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable` classes to the targeted element.
2 - `resizable` appends N number of div tags (depending upon the number of handles specified).

So, without removing appended div tags, containing the class name `ui-resizable-handle` and reattaching `draggable` and `resizable` duplicates child div tags with class name `ui-resizable-handle` and that's why i was removing them first.

Comment: Try it out storing the DOM in database containing `resizable` and `draggable` div tag and try to make it `resizable` again using jQuery and it won't work.

Comment: I managed to fixed it on that day. The strange thing is, it worked without jQuery ui css as well before and still working as long as I was storing the history log in localStorage. But the problem arise when I was trying to display the dom coming from database and i got it fixed with the jquery ui theme stylesheet.

Comment: Here's my [Fiddle](http://https://jsfiddle.net/zhtvyx4q/6/) which i forgot to share that day in which i fixed it myself